# Training GANs discriminator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I was referencing this tutorial site https://pathmind.com/wiki/generative-adversarial-network-gan

In this piece of code

```
class GAN():
    def __init__(self):
        self.img_rows = 28
        self.img_cols = 28
        self.channels = 1
        self.img_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)
        self.latent_dim = 100

        optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)

        # Build and compile the discriminator
        self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
        self.discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['accuracy'])

        # Build the generator
        self.generator = self.build_generator()

        # The generator takes noise as input and generates imgs
        z = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        img = self.generator(z)

        # For the combined model we will only train the generator
        self.discriminator.trainable = False

        # The discriminator takes generated images as input and determines validity
        validity = self.discriminator(img)

        # The combined model  (stacked generator and discriminator)
        # Trains the generator to fool the discriminator
        self.combined = Model(z, validity)
        self.combined.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

In the training portion

```
def train(self, epochs, batch_size=128, sample_interval=50):

        # Load the dataset
        (X_train, _), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()

        # Rescale -1 to 1
        X_train = X_train / 127.5 - 1.
        X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=3)

        # Adversarial ground truths
        valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
        fake = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))

        for epoch in range(epochs):

            # ---------------------
            #  Train Discriminator
            # ---------------------

            # Select a random batch of images
            idx = np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], batch_size)
            imgs = X_train[idx]

            noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, self.latent_dim))

            # Generate a batch of new images
            gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(noise)

            # Train the discriminator
            d_loss_real = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(imgs, valid)
            d_loss_fake = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, fake)
            d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)

            # ---------------------
            #  Train Generator
            # ---------------------

            noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, self.latent_dim))

            # Train the generator (to have the discriminator label samples as valid)
            g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch(noise, valid)

            # Plot the progress
            print ("%d [D loss: %f, acc.: %.2f%%] [G loss: %f]" % (epoch, d_loss[0], 100*d_loss[1], g_loss))

            # If at save interval => save generated image samples
            if epoch % sample_interval == 0:
                self.sample_images(epoch)
```

What i am confused is that in the initilization, the `self.discriminator.trainable = False` is already set.

How does the discriminator is being trained in the `train` method without setting it to be `true`. Wouldnt the `self.combined` would have the reference of the `self.discriminator` instead?

In this case, the `discriminator` would not be trained. Am i misunderstanding something?

> Blockquote

Comment: I'm working through that tutorial now.  It has errors in it.  He makes too many unnecessary layers.  Also, according to plot_model, his discriminator is sharing an input layer with the generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `model.trainable` is set to True. If you want to change it, it must be done before compiling the model. In your case,

```
        self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
        self.discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
        img = self.generator(z)

        # For the combined model we will only train the generator
        self.discriminator.trainable = False

        # The discriminator takes generated images as input and determines validity
        validity = self.discriminator(img)

        # The combined model  (stacked generator and discriminator)
        # Trains the generator to fool the discriminator
        self.combined = Model(z, validity)
        self.combined.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

Discriminator is compiled first and then comes the GAN part(`self.combined`).

You can check using:
 `print(self.discriminator.summary()) #equal number of trainable and non-trainable parameters`
`print(self.combined.summary()) #trainable parameters will be lesser than non- trainable parameters`

Correct me if I am wrong :)